# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
public function SelectLastError(){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Name, Data FROM Errors ORDER BY ErrorsId DESC LIMIT 3");
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
        }catch (PDOException $exception){
            echo  $exception->getMessage();
            echo "Error!";
            return null;
        }
    }
```

E estou tentando chamar ele em um HTML desse jeito:

```
<?php 
  $rows = $selectors->SelectLastError();
  foreach ($rows as $row):?>                            
     <a href="" class="list-group-item">
      <i class="fa fa-bug"></i><?php echo $row['Name'];?>
      <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em><?php echo $row['Data']?></em>
      </span>
     </a>                                
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Só que ele da o erro do título : "**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in**"

Já fiz essa mesma ideia em outro foreach, não sei o porque está aparecendo esse erro, o SELECT esta certo já testei.
Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Ironicamente isso significa que não tem erro O.o. Acredito que o jeito seja verificar se existe algum valor em `$rows`

Comment: @rray Pior que tem um erro na função hehehe, achei faltou um `return $rows;` no final

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tá dando error porque seu método não retorna um valor iterável via `foreach`.

O método `SelectLastError` deveria retornar um `array`, já que você quer usá-lo posteriormente em um `foreach`.

Você está adicionando os resultados em `$rows`. Então você também deveria ter retornado esse valor.

Veja:

```
function SelectLastError()
{
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Name, Data FROM Errors ORDER BY ErrorsId DESC LIMIT 3");
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        return $rows;

    }catch (PDOException $exception){
        echo  $exception->getMessage();
        echo "Error!";
        return null;
    }
}
```

## Recomendação

Se você quer agrupar os resultados, linha por linha, num `array` e, ao final, retorná-lo para usar em uma função, seria mais fácil usar uma solução que já está presente na linguagem. Ao invés de usar um `while` e salvar resultado por resultado no `array`, recomendo a modificação do método. Você vai substituir todo o trecho o `while` por `fetchAll`.

Veja:

```
function SelectLastError () {

    try {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Name, Data FROM Errors ORDER BY ErrorsId DESC LIMIT 3");

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }catch (PDOException $exception){
        echo  $exception->getMessage();
        echo "Error!";
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo falto o return, só vi agora. Obrigado

Comment: Mesmo assim, recomendo que faça como ensinei na segunda opção. Se você fizer do jeito que está atualmente, vai dar uma volta a toa, visto que o PHP já tem isso pronto.

Comment: Feito! Muito obrigado pela dica!